# Issues overriding the get_redirect_url function for the RedirectView generic view

Tags: django, django-views, url-routing, django-urls

So I'm trying to implement a post like Toggle for my Django blog - and I'm looking to override the get_redirect_url such that a user can like posts on my blog. I've outlined the class as follows:

```
class PostLikeToggle(RedirectView):

    def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        slug = self.kwargs.get("slug")
        obj = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
        url_ = obj.get_absolute_url()
        self.request.user

        if user.is_authenticated():
            obj.likes.add(user)
        return url_
```

*However*, the issue I think is in how I'm getting my post object - I'm currently doing this on the post slug. I have wanted to define SEO friendly post listings, I've therefore defined the url patterns as follows:

```
url_patterns = [
         url(r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})/(?P<day>\d{2})/'\
             r'(?P<post>[-\w]+)/$', views.post_detail, name = 'post_detail'),
         url(r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})/(?P<day>\d{2})/'\
             r'(?P<post>[-\w]+)/like/$', views.PostLikeToggle.as_view(), name = 'post_like'),
]
```

I've tried amending the above to reference the "slug" by replacing `<post>` with `<slug>` in the url. Didn't work. I then tried to define post in the get_redirect_url function:

```
        post = self.kwargs.get("post")
        obj = get_object_or_404(Post, post=post)
```

Again, didn't work. I'm just trying various things to try and get this to work - but sadly, no luck yet - so I though I would throw it out to the more experienced of you in the Django wrangling community.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your url pattern contains `(?P<post>[-\w]+)`, then you should use `self.kwargs.get("post")` instead of `self.kwargs.get("slug")`.

In `get_object_or_404`, you must use `slug=` and not `post=`, since you are filtering on the `Post.slug` field.

```
def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
    slug = self.kwargs.get("post")
    obj = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    ...
```

If the slug is only unique for each date rather than unique, then you might have to fetch `year`, `month` and `day` from `self.kwargs` as well.

Comment: Hi Alasdair - awesome, this is now working. Thank you. I have accepted the answer as correct (I can see why you have 115k, and then some!). On reflection, and your good words of advice, I should have kept `post=self.kwargs.get("post")` and used `obj = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=post)` (and not `obj = get_object_or_404(Post, post=post)`)

Comment: Yes, that's right, your problem was that you tried `post=` instead of `slug=` the `get_object_or_404`.